# Nokia phone not displayed in Finder?

Tags: lumia, 8.1, macos

My MacBook Pro is not listing my Nokia 635 in Finder:

[image]

What I should do to make the MBP show the Nokia?

---

Related: it appears OS X recognizes the device:

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType
USB:

    USB Hi-Speed Bus:

      Host Controller Location: Built-in USB
      Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBEHCI
      PCI Device ID: 0x1c2d 
      PCI Revision ID: 0x0005 
      PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086 
      Bus Number: 0xfa 

        Hub:

          Product ID: 0x2513
          Vendor ID: 0x0424  (SMSC)
          Version:  b.b3
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
          Location ID: 0xfa100000 / 3
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 2

            Nokia Lumia 635 (RM-975):

              Product ID: 0x06fc
              Vendor ID: 0x0421  (Nokia Corporation)
              Version: 1.00
              Serial Number: 11000000...
              Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
              Manufacturer: Nokia
              Location ID: 0xfa130000 / 6
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 500
    ...
```

---

Related: it appears the [Windows Phone App for Mac](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/windows-phone-7-connector/id415571499) is broken. I'm trying to access the file system on the phone using Finder. Cf., [Log files for Windows Phone App on Mac?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/5878/9341)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone **does not** currently support a USB mass storage option which is why no device or folders are listed in Finder on the Mac.

The **Windows Phone app** works fine, just make sure to give the app proper permission by going to File > Allow Access to Folder.